# Driver not updated on dimension changes

Tags: modifiers, objects, drivers, dimensions

This is the setup.

- Blue Slider.
- Green cube with array modifier.
- Red cube.

The Blue slider drives the Green cube's array property count when moved up/down and works perfect.
[image]

The red box is set to move its location to the green box's `location.x+dimension[0]`.
If I resize the green box or move it, the red cube is following the green box's end correctly (`location.x+dimension[0]`).

[image]
However, If I change the Green box's count property in the Array modifier (with or without Blue slider driver), the red box's location isn't updated at all.

To update it I have to set the cursor in the drivers Expression box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It seems like the driver isn't triggered when the array count property changes the cube's dimension.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: I know this use to work, an example in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ILT2KRF0r58&list=PLYmUVj7xM5ui6pF6yjKW-_lNhAjnJOJvy#t=1392) video. I can not get it to work ether, which makes me think it might be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the red cube a dependency on the blue slider. Do this by adding a new variable as the slider location.z, you don't need to use this variable in your expression calculation but having it there adds a dependency that updates the location as you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.